# How do I integrate this function in this non-rectangular region?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, math-software

I'm trying to numerically integrate the function $$I(\mu) =\exp{(-\tau/\beta)} I_0[1-u_1 (1 - \mu)-u_2 (1-\mu)^2], $$ $I_0$, $u_1$ , $u_2$, $\tau$ and $\beta$ are known, and $$\mu = \sqrt{1-(x^2+z^2)}$$

Now it comes the difficult part. The nasty non-rectangular region where I want the integral is: 
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
R_{in} ^2 < \left(\frac{x-X_p-(z-Z_p)\cdot\sin \phi}{\cos \theta}\right)^2 + (\frac{z-Z_p}{\sin\theta})^2<R_{out}^2 \\
x^2+z^2<1 \\
(x-X_p)^2+(z-Z_p)^2>R_p^2
\end{array}\right.
$$

$R_p<R_{in}<R_{out}$, $R_{p}<1$, $X_p$ and $Z_p$ all are known.

I tried to use software to numerically solve it, such as MATLAB, Python or Mathematica. But the problem I have is that I can't parametrize this region in order to be able to integrate it. So, what can I use to numerically solve it? Do I need to parametrize it?.

Pd: another thing I tried is integrate the function in a piecewise function (where the function is 0 outside the region), using the trapeze method. But it doesn't work since I have to deal with discontinuities. So, what should I do?

Comment: Generally you need an indicator function which is one on the domain of interest, and zero elsewhere. Then integrate over a minimal rectangular superset. This ruins all the properties of the integrand, but if you just need the job done it'll work.

Comment: I've done that in MATLAB, but again, the problem is that you can't numerically integrate a discontinuous function, and I can't integrate in a non-rectangular region in Matlab (I think)

Comment: You can numerically integrate a discontinuous function.

Comment: Actually I couldn't, it gave me accuracy problems in the discontinuities, the error "Warning: Reached the maximum number of function evaluations (2000). The result fails the global error test.". That error disappeared when I integrate outside the discontinuities.

Comment: 2000 is not near enough in 3D. Try 1000,000

Comment: I tried 100,000 and more, and it gives me the same. It's clearly because of the discontinuities.

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding, it appears to be a 2D integral... moreover, the 1st inequality appears to describe an "annular region" bounded by two ellipses, while the second two inequalities seem to describe the interior & exterior of two discs, respectively.  Is this correct, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Yes, that's it basically.

Comment: One possibility - use [DistMesh](http://persson.berkeley.edu/distmesh/) (Matlab software written by [Prof. Persson](http://persson.berkeley.edu/)) to create a triangulation $\mathcal{T}$ of the domain of integration $\Omega$.  Next, approximate the integral of $I(\mu)$ on each triangle by some quadrature rule $Q(I_0; K)$, where $K \in \mathcal{T}$ denotes a triangle.  (See [`quadpy` on Github](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy) for references.)  Then, compute the sum $\sum_{K \in \mathcal{T}} Q(I_0; K)$ -- this is the approximation of $\int_\Omega I(\mu) ~ dx ~ dz$.

Comment: @CarlosVázquezMonzón, a more easily-accesesible reference (regarding quadrature rules for triangles) might be this answer I posted a few years ago (which I had forgotten about until today) -- https://math.stackexchange.com/a/527572/97353