How do I calculate this integral? (FEM)
I am currently working on a FEM project where I have to implement to solve the Stokes Equations using a FEM method using triangular elements and in particular the GLS-stabilized P1/P1 space:

However I am stuck in evaluating the necessary integrals to implement in Matlab.
How do I evaluate this integral ?:
$$
f_{i} = \int_{T} f \cdot \phi_{i} \, \mathrm{d}x\quad\mbox{where}\quad\varphi_{i}^{(T)}(x,y)=\frac{\alpha_{i}^{(T)}+\beta_{i}^{(T)} x+\gamma_{i}^{(T)} y}{2|T|}
$$
I think I need to use the quadrature rule to evaluate the integral of f but I do not know how to solve this integral since there is also the basis function.

Thank you.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525732/gaussian-integration-on-triangles
